# Pairing elements without repeating

Tags: python, indexing

I am close to figuring out this problem but am hung on one one thing in particular. I am trying to pair/zip together elements in a list pair by pair, and then checking which value is greater. I just can't figure out how to pair these elements without repeating values.

```
[35,10,5,3,1,26,15]
```

I do NOT want:

```
[35,10], [10,5]
```

I DO want:

```
[35,10], [5,3]
```

Here is my code:

```
def queue_time(customers, n):
    time_left = 0
    max_val = max(customers[:n])
    total_time = int(max_val)
    other_customers = list(customers)
    other_customers.remove(max_val)

for idx, el in enumerate(other_customers):
    if max_val > 0:
        nxt_till_times = other_customers[idx:idx+n-1] 
        max_other_tills = max(nxt_till_times)
        max_val -= max_other_tills
        print nxt_till_times
    elif max_val == 0:
        max_val = max(customers[idx:idx+n])
        total_time += max_val
    elif max_val < 0:
        time_left = [-1*(max_val)]
        others_still = time_left + customers[idx+1:]
        max_val = max(others_still[:n])
        total_time += max_val

#print total_time
return total_time

queue_time([35,10,5,3,1,26,15], 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
>>> l = [35,10,5,3,1,26,15]
>>> [l[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(l)-1, 2)]
[[35, 10], [5, 3], [1, 26]]
```

This will cut off any odd-numbered elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [35,10,5,3,1,26,15]
g = (i for i in l)
output = [(next(g), next(g)) for i in range(len(l)//2)]
```

`g` is a generator.  This doesn't do anything with the last element of odd-length lists.  That element is available at `next(g)`